# Why did Snotlout say, "That's two for me"?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

In *How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World* (2019), Snotlout is about to lose the fight, but Hookfang spits fire at the Trapper, 
saving his rider.

> Snotlout: Yee-ha! **That's two for me**!

Why did Snotlout say, "That's two for me"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the joke is that Snotlout had no part in the victory, but due to his egotism, he's claiming that he was the one who defeated the Trapper. Prior to that, Astrid had taken down a Trapper, so the "two for me" suggests that either Snotlout has taken credit for that takedown too, or he's just inflating his numbers to try to sound more impressive. From [the wiki entry for Snotlout](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Snotlout_Jorgenson):

> Snotlout is highly an arrogant, bordering on narcissistic and prone guy to grandiose delusions of perfection, popularity and extreme attractiveness and consequentially his egomania causes him to have a huge problem with authority or being able to admit responsibility for his mistakes or misdeeds, for which he always has some terrible justification. He appears to consider himself the smartest and strongest of the teens and wants to be praised and admired accordingly, despite the others usually considering him an annoying, immature idiot with a colossal ego. His selfishness and egomania cause him to often be inconsiderate and exploitative towards others, and will often put the others down to make himself look better. In interviews, Jonah Hill has said that deep down Snotlout knows he is not the best but still wants to be thought of as such, implying his vainglorious posing is more about overcompensation. He likes to think he can handle everything, but when he can't, he is not above asking for help. He is confrontational, brutally frank, and stubborn.